# Ubuntu Remap script for UK Logitech Cordless Wave Keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, keyboard

I have just bought a Logitech Cordless Wave UK Keyboard and mouse and I'm trying to get the keymapping sorted but not having much luck!

The main problem I have is none of the key seem to give me the HASH symbol.

Ideally I'm after a remapping script that I can get to run at start up or even a GUI based remapping software so I can get my keys to print what is actually label on each key!

I have tried HIDPoint but I'm using VMWare to run Ubuntu 10.04 and it didn't recognise the keyboard or mouse

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm going to start with the fact that I think that perhaps your keyboard layout was not properly detected by xorg. If the keyboard as special keys I think there's a logitech-daemon of some kind that will allow you to use them. Barring anyone else's help those might be things you search for.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see what keyboard layout is being used by opening the Keyboard settings dialog (`System > Preferences > Keyboard`) and selecting the `Layouts` tab.

Also, there is a [bug report on Launchpad (#592371)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/592371) related to the Logitech Cordless Wave Pro key mappings. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and it looks like the changes made by the [upstream patch](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/hotplug/udev.git;a=commitdiff;h=0fade61274497b874a7446fdd35bb7e1f5856f08) referenced in that bug have been applied in the current [udev package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/udev) (151-12.1).